# Audio Reproduction Simulator

Tags: python, matlab, audio-recording, simulator

I have two wav files which are target sound and background noise. I have implemented the target sound, 2 sec sound clip, into background noise, 10 sec sound clip. Then with the help of common deep learning models like YamNet, I detected the sound event. That's OK.

If it had been really recorded it with microphones, the distance and angle of the source would also be determinant parameters. In order to be more realistic, I want to simulate these.

I need a program or model which I will give it readily downloaded wav file from internet. Then the program/model reproduces a new wav file with the given wav file as if they were recorded from a specific distance and angle. Therefore, I can also check the effect of these parameters.
So, is there any program or model that can simulate this recording?